# Angular --prod build succeeds but UI does not display

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Using angular-cli 1.3.1/Angular 4.3.5

Insight on this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Angular dev build succeeds and displays without issue. Angular prod builds succeeds but fails to display due to this error.

```
vendor.4b0119a81d0c1aee597c.bundle.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at vendor.4b0119a81d0c1aee597c.bundle.js:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at t.visitTrigger (vendor.4b0119a81d0c1aee597c.bundle.js:1)
    at S (vendor.4b0119a81d0c1aee597c.bundle.js:1)
    at t.build (vendor.4b0119a81d0c1aee597c.bundle.js:1)
    at j (vendor.4b0119a81d0c1aee597c.bundle.js:1)
    at e.t.registerTrigger (vendor.4b0119a81d0c1aee597c.bundle.js:1)
    at vendor.4b0119a81d0c1aee597c.bundle.js:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at t.createRenderer (vendor.4b0119a81d0c1aee597c.bundle.js:1)
    at vendor.4b0119a81d0c1aee597c.bundle.js:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at t.visitTrigger (vendor.4b0119a81d0c1aee597c.bundle.js:1)
    at S (vendor.4b0119a81d0c1aee597c.bundle.js:1)
    at t.build (vendor.4b0119a81d0c1aee597c.bundle.js:1)
    at j (vendor.4b0119a81d0c1aee597c.bundle.js:1)
    at e.t.registerTrigger (vendor.4b0119a81d0c1aee597c.bundle.js:1)
    at vendor.4b0119a81d0c1aee597c.bundle.js:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at t.createRenderer (vendor.4b0119a81d0c1aee597c.bundle.js:1)
    at s (polyfills.4e7a82003010f988c738.bundle.js:1)
    at s (polyfills.4e7a82003010f988c738.bundle.js:1)
    at polyfills.4e7a82003010f988c738.bundle.js:1
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.4e7a82003010f988c738.bundle.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.4b0119a81d0c1aee597c.bundle.js:1)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.4e7a82003010f988c738.bundle.js:1)
    at r.runTask (polyfills.4e7a82003010f988c738.bundle.js:1)
    at i (polyfills.4e7a82003010f988c738.bundle.js:1)
    at <anonymous>
b @ vendor.4b0119a81d0c1aee597c.bundle.js:1
```

The error is occurring in the following source

```
        t.prototype.visitTrigger = function(t, e) {
            var n = this
              , r = e.queryCount = 0
              , o = e.depCount = 0
              , i = []
              , a = [];
            t.definitions.forEach(function(t) {
                if (n._resetContextStyleTimingState(e),
                0 == t.type) {
                    var s = t
                      , l = s.name;
                    l.split(/\s*,\s*/).forEach(function(t) {
                        s.name = t,
                        i.push(n.visitState(s, e))
                    }),
                    s.name = l
                } else if (1 == t.type) {
                    var u = n.visitTransition(t, e);
                    r += u.queryCount,
                    o += u.depCount,
                    a.push(u)
                } else
                    e.errors.push("only state() and transition() definitions can sit inside of a trigger()")
            });
            var s = new Dt(t.name,i,a);
            return s.options = L(t.options),
            s.queryCount = r,
            s.depCount = o,
            s
        }
```

Comment: did you include a reference to core-js?

Comment: can you try using ng serve --aot

Comment: @pixelbits there are references to core-js in src/pollyfills.ts but no references in my code

Comment: @Rahul same result as with --prod (the split error)

Comment: update npm dependencies and try.

Comment: @pritesh we're using the latest versions of all components